# Processing: Accessing IP Camera

Tags: video-streaming, processing, video-capture, ip-camera

How do I access an IP Camera using the language Processing. I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find a method to do so. Anyone with any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try it out right now but the **[video library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/index.html)** may be what you're looking for.

Try out the sample code from the Processing Reference:

> **Capture**: datatype for storing and manipulating video frames from an attached
>   capture device such as a camera. Use *Capture.list()* to show the names
>   of any attached devices. Using the version of the constructor without
>   name will attempt to use the last device used by a QuickTime program. – **[Processing Reference](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Capture.html)**

If you encounter any issue, check the related **[Wiki page](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Video_Issues)**.